# Can't capture inbound/outbound messages in Fiddler

Tags: networking, proxy, tcp, sniffing, http-proxy

.NET interferes with localhost traffic (there's already a lot of threads open on that topic), but something else is mangling my ability to see traffic to/from my server.

I know this because I am talking with (successfully) external servers with real, external, non-loopback IP's.

But it doesn't show up in Fiddler.

I tried the tricks on teleric.com where you add some bypassproxy=false configs, but that didn't solve anything either.

Wireshark is like a firehose, and I'm not sure even then that it's picking up the messages I want.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to Wireshark you can add filters to just capture traffic related to your servers IP address (see filter below).

```
ip.dst == 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: Ah ... looks like I neglected to click "apply".